# How to sort a range based on the value of some transformation of its values?

Tags: c++, performance, sorting, boost, transform

Let `arr` be an array of some type `T` and `func(const &T)` some computationally expensive function. To sort `arr` by the value of `func(T)`, we could naively write.

```
std::sort(arr.begin(), arr.end(), [](const T& a, const T&b) {
    return func(a) < func(b);
}
```

However this will invoke `func` O(nlogn) times on average. Obviously, we need no more than exactly n invocations. Is there any idiomatic and concise way to do this?

I am aware of the following two solutions but I would like to find one that is better.

- Packing the `T`s and the return value of `func` in a struct and sorting that. This is optimal computationally but it also does one full copy of the initial array before sorting and another full copy afterwards to put the values back into `arr`
- Creating a second array and sorting the arrays in parallel. As far as I know there is no idiomatic way to sort two arrays that way. It could be done by writing custom iterators and a swap function. That's good enough but it also requires a bit more boilerplate code than ideal.

The ideal solution would be STL-based with as little boilerplate code as possible, but all contributions are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

## First non-generic solution

What you need is kind of memoization of function result. If your function `fun` does not have side effects and from using it in `std::sort` I infer it does not I would think of something like this:

```
#include <unordered_map>

template<class T, class U>
class caller{
public:
    const U &call(const T& t) const{
        auto found = memoized.find(t);
        if (found != memoized.end())
            return found->second;

        return memoized.insert(std::make_pair(t, fun(t))).first->second;
    }
private:
    mutable std::unordered_map<T, U> memoized;
};
```

Its usage would look like this:

```
caller<T, decltype(func(std::declval<T>()))> c;
std::sort(arr.begin(), arr.end(), [](const T& a, const T&b) {
    return c.call(a) < c.call(b);
}
```

## More generic solution

After making first solution I played a bit and made a bit more generic, C++17 compliant one. It should work with every function taking one argument that is coypable and hashable. Take a look:

```
#include <unordered_map>

int fii(int){
    return 0;
}

template<class T, auto fun>
class memoizer{
public:
    const auto &call(const T& t) const{
        auto found = memoized.find(t);
        if (found != memoized.end())
            return found->second;

        return memoized.insert(std::make_pair(t,  fun(t)))
            .first->second;
    }
private:
    mutable std::unordered_map<T, decltype(fun(T()))> memoized;
};

auto memoized_fii = memoizer<int, fii>{};
```

Comment: This is pretty good. The only requirement is that T is hashable, correct?

Comment: @patatahooligan it has to be copyable to add it to map AFAIK, same for the result

Comment: You can return a `const&` to the value in the map and use `std::move(result)` to move it in to avoid 2 copies.